# Python Adjacency Matrix using TXT files & panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, adjacency-matrix

I want to build a csv adjacency matrix using lots of .txt files. I've been trying to build it iteratively using panda but running into issues with the insert function. The txt file format is:

```
326869253   1386884701
326869253   7587032
326869253   11609972
49053573    7587032
18869940    7587032
...         ...        <-- example table ends here
18869940    35706421
200757425   7587032
801698222   7587032
18950342    7587032
```

Where the matrix would be 1 as described by each line:
Ex. The value of the cell at column name 326869253 and row name 1386884701 would be 1, but not at column name 1386884701 and row name 326869253, unless specified later. There are repeat values obviously, so I'm running into issues filling the column and row values. The example csv would end up being:

```
0          326869253  1386884701  7587032  11609972 49053573 18869940
326869253          0           1        1         1        0        0
1386884701         0           0        0         0        0        0
7587032            0           0        0         0        0        0
11609972           0           0        0         0        0        0
49053573           0           0        1         0        0        0
18869940           0           0        1         0        0        0
```

I originally built the initial columns and rows by getting a list of all values and converting it into a set (to get rid of duplicate values), then turning it back into a list and initializing it into a dataframe, but I'd like to build the dataframe while the program reads the new information from the txt files.
Thanks

Comment: I think the approach you abandoned is much cleaner: preallocate `df.index` and `df.columns` using the unique set of vertices. Why not use that?

Comment: For runtime reasons - there are ~17,000 unique numbers, so I'll be making a 17000 by 17000 size matrix